# To specify a DataGridView column header's text with an event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I used another way of assigning a DGW's column header text below, but after I debugged below event causes to run a good number of cells in the DGW. Of course we cannot except a different behave with this event's approach but how I can use a better way that runs one time to assign texts for columns header.

```
private void DGWBase_ColumnHeaderCellChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e) 
{
    DGWBase.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Waktu Mulai\nStarting Time";
    DGWBase.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Nama Personil\nPersonnel Name";
    DGWBase.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Nama Pekerjaan\nWorkshop Name";
    DGWBase.Columns[3].HeaderText = "MPS No";
    DGWBase.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Kuantitas\nQuantity";
    DGWBase.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Operasi Kode\nOperation Code";
    DGWBase.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Nama Operasi\nOperation Name";
    DGWBase.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Produk Kode\nProduct Code";
    DGWBase.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Nama Produk\nProduct Name";
    DGWBase.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Permintaan Kersa\nJob Order"; 
}
```

Comment: what is the unexpected result of the code?

Comment: ColumnHeaderCellChanged event runs as much as number of cells which contain by the DataGridView. This is inappropriate approach. Let's say that event will run 1000 times if the Datagridview has that number of cells in it.

Comment: How do you trigger this event? I have to manually reset a column's `HeaderCell` like this:  `DGWBase.Columns[0].HeaderCell = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell();`, and the event handler is only executed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out DataGridView, DataBindingComplete Event and used my code lines in that event then Voila. This event runs one and that is quite good solution for my aim. Thanks @kennyzx.

```
private void DGWBase_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        DGWBase.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Waktu Mulai\nStarting Time";
        DGWBase.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Nama Personil\nPersonnel Name";
        DGWBase.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Nama Pekerjaan\nWorkshop Name";
        DGWBase.Columns[4].HeaderText = "MPS No";
        DGWBase.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Kuantitas\nQuantity";
        DGWBase.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Operasi Kode\nOperation Code";
        DGWBase.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Nama Operasi\nOperation Name";
        DGWBase.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Produk Kode\nProduct Code";
        DGWBase.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Nama Produk\nProduct Name";
        DGWBase.Columns[10].HeaderText = "Permintaan Kersa\nJob Order";
    }
```